# A conformal equivalence between the disk and an infinite strip preserves angles at almost every boundary point?

Tags: complex-analysis

A conformal equivalence between the open unit disk in the complex plane and a region bounded by a Jordan curve can be extended to a continuous function on the closed unit disk, and this extension preserves angles at almost every boundary point.

What if the boundary of the region is not a Jordan curve, but the conformal map can be extended continuously for almost every point of the closed unit disk?

For example, if we have the conformal map from the disk to the strip $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < Re(z) < 1\}$ given by

\begin{equation*}
F(z) = \frac{-i}{\pi}\log(i\frac{1 - z}{1 + z})
\end{equation*}

will it preserve angles at almost every point $e^{i\theta}$, $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of the strip $S$ is a Jordan curve on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.  You can use a fractional linear transformation to map $S$ onto a bounded domain, i.e., $z\mapsto 1/(z+1)$ will do for your example. Apply the theorem to the composition, and observe that the fractional linear transformation preserves angles everywhere.

---

Also, for the specific example of the infinite strip one can use the reflection principle to show that $f$ extends to a conformal map between larger domains. This implies conformality on the boundary, except for the two points mapped to infinity.

---

More generally: the boundary behavior of a conformal map is a local issue. If a part of the boundary is good enough to apply a theorem of this kind, then the conclusion of that theorem holds locally. (Yes this is vague, but the inspection of the proof usually shows this to be true).